# Should I use Map<string, Map<string, object>> or Map<string, object> and concat the two keys

Tags: performance, data-structures

I'm working on processing some data and I need to keep a previous state. That state data structure would be something like

```js
type locationId = string;


type alarm = {
    alarmId : string,
    triggered: Date,
    urgency: string
}

type stateData = Map<locationId, Map<alarmId, alarm>> OR Map<locationId+alarmId, alarm>;
```

In pseudocode it would look like:

```
for each alarm in alarmList
    compare(lastState[locationId][alarm.alarmId], alarm)
```

or if I concat the two keys:

```
for each alarm in alarmList
    compare(lastState[locationId + "-" + alarmId], alarm)
```

Which one is the best approach?

Comment: Concatenating strings to be used as keys is almost every time the wrong approach. Use a custom type to represent your key. But having a map of maps doesn't sound too bad. Any problems that you have encountered? And the answer probably highly depends on the language/runtime being used

Comment: Besides the issue with string concatenation pointed out by knittl (you just need to use a pair with a good hash function for this type if you use a hash-based map), the answer dependent of the actual size of the two maps. The first does 2 indirection while the second does 1 unique indirection. The thing is the big map replicates its key so it has a bigger overhead and it is certainly much bigger since it merge the 2 maps. The cache size also matters regarding the size of the maps. Tree-based maps and Hash-based maps might also behave differently (regarding the unspecified target language)

Answer (score 0):

How you do this will depend on your data and how you want to access it, and perhaps most importantly how you want to think about it.

Consider the dictionary with a combined key. Something like

```
type alarmKey = {
    locationId: string;
    alarmId: string;
}

type alarms = Map<alarmKey, stateData>
```

With that design, you have to know the location and the alarm ID if you want to look up an alarm. There's no quick way, for example, to get all of the alarms for a particular location. Instead, you have to scan the entire dictionary looking for alarms where `alarmKey.locationId="Desired location"`.

That might not be a bad thing. If your total number of alarms is small (i.e. the map isn't huge) or if getting the list of alarms for a single location isn't a common operation, then that's not a bad thing.

Do note, by the way, that if you go that route you'll need to define a hash code method that will create a hash code for the combined key. You don't say what language you're using. In C#, that method could be as simple as:

```
return (locationId+alarmId).GetHashCode();
```

(Yes, I know that it's a horribly inefficient way to compute a hash code for a combined key. But it will in fact work. I'll leave coming up with a better one as a detail to be resolved by the implementor.)

The other way, with a nested map, seems more flexible to me. That is:

```
type alarms = Map<locationId, Map<alarmId, stateData>>
```

That lets you easily get all alarms for a single location, and it's also easy to look up an individual alarm.

You're probably going to supply an accessor anyway, so either way will be just as easy to *use*. That is, regardless of which way you design it, you'll probably have a getter function:

```
alarm GetAlarm(locationId, alarmId)
{
}
```

And of course a corresponding setter function.

I don't have knowledge of your application, but when I've encountered this kind of thing in the past my immediate preference is for the nested maps because I find it more flexible. But I readily admit that it's largely a subjective thing, and dependent on the application.